# how get target children id

Tags: jquery, html, find, children

short english...

my html

```
<button><span id="popMain"> pop </span></button>

$(document).bind({
click : function(evt){
var targetID = evt.target.id;
var nodeName = evt.target.nodeName;
}
```

- click event from chrome ( nodeName : SPAN )
- click event from explorer (nodename : BUTTON)

when use explorer, i want get **span's ID.**

i try

```
$(this).find('span').attr('id');
$(this).find('span').id;
$("#"+evt.target.id).children('span').attr('id');
$("#"+evt.target.id).find('span:first-child').attr('id');
$("#"+evt.target.id).find('span:last-child').attr('id');
```

but result is 'undifined'. T^T
plz help me...

Comment: change `$("#"+evt.target.id).childeren('span').attr('id');` to `$("#"+evt.target.id).children('span').attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake:

```
$(this).find('span').attr('id');
$(this).find('span').id;
$("#"+evt.target.id).childeren('span').attr('id'); // children not childeren.
$("#"+evt.target.id).find('span:first-child').attr('id');
$("#"+evt.target.id).find('span:last-child').attr('id');
```

Comment: thanks.. T^T i solve.. [ $("#"+evt.target.id).children('span').attr('id'); ]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on explorer :

```
$("span:first").attr('id');
```